# preg_match pattern dosn't work in php v 5

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i am using php version 5.4.45 .
i test this code in php version 7 and work true but not work in version 5.4.45

```
$string = '9301234567';
if( preg_match('/^\9\d{9}/', $string) ) 
{
    $string = '0+1'.$string ;
    return $string ;
}
```

in v7 return :

```
0+19301234567
```

but in v5.4.45 return (preg_match return false)

```
9301234567
```

how i can use `preg_match('/^\9\d{9}/', $string)`  in php v5.4.45 ?
Thanks

Comment: Use `/^9\d{9}/`

Comment: I have tested your code on https://3v4l.org/#preview and it worked with 5.4.45.

Comment: Escaping word chars makes no sense and leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Brief

Your pattern is `/^\9\d{9}/`. Note that there's a `\9` in there. This is usually interpreted as a backreference (which is what's happening in your earlier version of PHP). I guess the interpreter is now smarter and realizes your subpattern `\9` doesn't exist and so it understands it as a literal `9` instead.

#### Edit - Research

I dug deeper into this change in behaviour and in [PHP 5.5.10 they upgraded PCRE to version 8.34](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.10). Looking through the [changelogs for PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/original/changelog.txt), now, I discovered that version 8.34 of PCRE introduced the following change:

> 21. Perl has changed its handling of \8 and \9. If there is no previously
>       encountered capturing group of those numbers, they are treated as the
>       literal characters 8 and 9 instead of a binary zero followed by the
>       literals. PCRE now does the same.

---

### Code

Use this regex instead.

```
/^9\d{9}/
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76943bc5e1185e572efdcaa799d1d35e3858079b)

```
<?php

$string = '9301234567';
if( preg_match('/^9\d{9}/', $string) ) 
{
    $string = '0+1'.$string ;
    print $string ;
}
```

Comment: Such deep level of knowledge.+1

Answer (score 1):

Tested this in both php 5.34 and php 7.01:

```
$string = '9301234567';
if( preg_match('/^9\d{9}/', $string) ) 
{
    $string = '0+1'.$string ;
    return $string ;
}
```

No need for the `\` before the first `9`

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$string = '9301234567';
if( preg_match('/^[9]\d{9}/', $string) ) 
{
    $string = '0+1'.$string ;
    return $string ;
}
```